# How to check the Text is null or not using JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I write these codes

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
q.setFilter("textPosts != null"); // textPosts is a Text
List<User> users = (List<User>) q.execute();
resp.getWriter().println("user num: " + users.size());
```

And I get

```
user num: 0
```

I'm sure that the number should greater than 0.
I probably miss something important.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Querying Unindexed properties](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Introduction_to_Indexes):

`A query with a filter or sort order on a property will never match an entity with that property unindexed`

So your entity is not found because Text properties are never indexed.

This is also relevant (but in your case Text being unindexed prevails) - [entities with non-existing properties are not found with queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Object_Fields_and_Entity_Properties):

`The App Engine datastore distinguishes between an entity without a given property and an entity with a null value for a property. JDO does not support this distinction: every field of an object has a value, possibly null.`

So if you have an Entity without a property, then it will not be found with a query, since a [query requires that the property exists](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries).

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to query a Text, it will always be not found?

Comment: Yes, you can not query on unindexed properties. Text is always unindexed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `Text` *will not be indexed for query purposes*, as it specified in javadoc: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text.html

Btw, i'm sure that it must throw exception at this case.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't receive any exception.

Comment: That's bad, for GAE. It throws similar exeptions, when you have misconfigured index, seems that it's not for your case.